# $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = 0$. Is it possible to have $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

> Suppose we have two functions $g(x), f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = 0$ Is it possible to have
>   $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$$

If it is not possible, can you explain/prove why it is so?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x^2}$

Comment: @MartinR the limit is undefined because from the left, you hit negative infinity. Therefore, $$\frac{x}{x^3}$$

Comment: @ChristopherMarley: Then take absolute values: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{x^2}$

Comment: Then do $\frac {x^2}{x^4}$

Comment: Essentially, any function $$\frac{x^n}{x^{n+2k}}$$ for $n,k>0$ is a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, consider $f(x) = |x - a|$ and $g(x) = (x-a)^2$.

$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 
\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $f(x)$ such that
$f(x) \to 0$,
let
$g(x) = f^2(x)$.

Then
$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}
=\dfrac{f(x)}{f^2(x)}
=\dfrac1{f(x)}
\to \infty$.